# A sufficient and necessary condition for $\mathbb{C}(f(x),g(x))=\mathbb{C}(x)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, field-theory, function-fields

Let $f=f(x),g=g(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

> Is there a sufficient and necessary condition for $\mathbb{C}(f(x),g(x))=\mathbb{C}(x)$?

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.3752.pdf) is perhaps relevant, although it deals with polynomials in two variables. Here we can also define 'good' or 'bad' field generator $f$ according to the existence of $g \in k[x]$ or $g \in k(x)$. But actually, every $f$ is a bad generator, since taking $g:=\frac{x}{f}$ yields $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(f,\frac{x}{f})=\mathbb{C}(x)$.

See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299842/a-sufficient-condition-for-two-bivariate-polynomials-to-generate-mathbbcx-y).

Thank you very much!

Comment: What kind of condition are you looking for? One obvious condition (mostly useless in practice) is that for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$, the greatest common divisor of $f(x)-a, g(x)-b$ is $x-c$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not sure what kind of condition I am looking for (probably a condition that I will be able to apply in practice). The condition you suggested sounds interesting, and it would be nice if you could write it as an answer (with more elaboration, please).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes. Let $\mathbb{C}[f(x),g(x)]\subset A\subset \mathbb{C}[x]$, where $A$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{C}[f,g]$ in its fraction field. Then it is well known that $A=\mathbb{C}[u(x)]$ for some polynomial $u(x)$. Now, let $c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that the gcd of $p=f(x)-f(c), q= g(x)-g(c)$ is precisely $x-c$. This implies $p,q\in A$ are not relatively prime and so some non-constant polynomial $h(u)$ divides both. Then $h(u(x))$ divides both $p,q$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$, and so by assumption, $h(u(x))$ must have degree one in $x$. Then, $u$ must also be of degree one in $x$ and thus $A=\mathbb{C}[x]$. Since the fraction fileds of $\mathbb{C}[f,g]$ is the same as that of $A$, we are done.

Comment: Very nice! (though I have not yet checked all the details; hopefully, I will soon).

Comment: What about the other direction? Namely, why  $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(x)$ implies the existence of $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=x-c$? (You probably think that this direction is trivial).

Comment: @user237522 Yes, it is trivial.

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see the trivial argument. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c