# Weak Nullstellensatz in practice

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field (I do not mind to assume $k=\mathbb{C}$).
Let $f(x),g(x) \in k[x]$.
[Hilbert's weak nullstellensatz](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/hilberts-nullstellensatz/) says that exactly one of the following statements holds:

**(1)** $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a common zero $c \in k$ (namely, $f(c)=g(c)=0$).

**(2)** There exist polynomials $a(x),b(x) \in k[x]$ such that $af+bg=1$ (namely, $f$ and $g$ generate the unit ideal in $k[x]$).

> Can one 'characterize' (= present in a general form in terms of coefficients and degrees) all $f(x),g(x)$ that do not satisfy $af+bg=1$ for all $a,b \in k[x]$, namely, $f$ and $g$ that have a common zero?

Of course, for such $f$ and $g$, the greatest common divisor is divisible by $x-d$ for some $d \in k$. But is it possible to say more? For example, if all monomials in $f$ and $g$ are of even degrees (including zero)?

Another question: What is the 'solution' to: $f,g \in k[x]$, $\deg(f),\deg(g) \geq 2$, $k(f,g)=k(x)$ (so by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx/2805821#2805821), the greatest common divisor of $f-\alpha,g-\beta$ is $x-\gamma$, for some $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in k$) and $f',g'$ generate the unit ideal in $k[x]$: $af'+bg'=1$ for some $a,b \in k[x]$ ($f'$ is the derivative of $f$).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you heard of resultants?

Comment: Yes, and here also relevant $D$-resultants  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240499500116E 
                    ($k(f,g)=k(x)$ if and only if thier $D$ resultant is non-zero). However, in practice, I am not sure if they help, but I hope/guess I am wrong.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2161575 (Proposition 0.2) is also relevant. Perhaps I should not be lazy, and try to apply the theory of resultants to general $f$ and $g$. I hope this would yield something. (Especially, my second question in low dimensions-- it seems that resultants may help: $f-\alpha$ and $g-\beta$ have one common root, while $f'$ and $g'$ do not).