# Concerning possible degrees of certain $f,g \in k[t]$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials, commutative-algebra, resultant

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, $k \in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$.
Ler $f=f(t),g=g(t) \in k[t]$ such that:

**(1)** The ideal in $k[t]$ generated by $f',g'$ (formal derivatives of $f,g$, respectively) is $k[t]$.

**(2)** $k(f,g)=k(t)$ (actually, it is possible to show that this follows from **(1)**).

**(3)** $\deg(f)=dn$, $\deg(g)=dm$, where $n < m$
and $d=\gcd(\deg(f),\deg(g))>1$.
($\gcd(n,m)$ is not known;
we wish to obtain $\gcd(n,m)=n$).

**(4)** Both $f$ and $g$ have monomials of all possible degrees,
namely, $f=\sum_{i=0}^{dn} a_i t^i$, $g=\sum_{i=0}^{dm} b_i t^j$,
where $a_i,b_j \in k-\{0\}$ for *all* $0 \leq i \leq dn, 0 \leq j \leq dm$.

> **Question 1:** What additional conditions are required (hopefully, none) in order to guarantee that there exist $u=u(t),v=v(t) \in k[t]$, such that:
>
> **(i)** $u,v \in k[f,g]$.
>
> **(ii)** $\deg(u)=dn-c, \deg(v)=dm-c$, where $1 \leq c \leq \min(dn,dm)$.
>
> It is possible to show that if conditions **(i)** and **(ii)** are satisfied, then $\deg(f)$ divides $\deg(g)$.

**Remarks:**

**I** **(2)** is equivalent to: The sub-resultant of $f$ and $g$ is non-zero;
see [Theorem 2.1](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-03/S0002-9939-97-03639-3/home.html)

**II** I think it is allowed that $c=dn$, and then **(ii)** becomes: $\deg(u)=0, \deg(v)=dm-dn$.

---

Independently of conditions **(i)** and **(ii)** of **Question 1**,
we can ask:

> **Question 2:** What additional conditions are required in rder to guarantee that $\deg(f)$ divides $\deg(g)$.

Perhaps the following nice answers may help here: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c).

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: It is a bit unclear... $u=f$, $v=g$, $c=0$ works?

Comment: @Mindlack, thank you for your important comment. I forgot to require that $c \geq 1$. I will now add this.

Comment: As it is it seems like arbitrary restrictions, so what is it useful for, where does it come from ?

Comment: You are right that you wish to know the motivation for the question; it comes from SAGBI bases, especially the following paper: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82116992.pdf The restrictions are not arbitrary, they come from Theorem 15 of the above paper.

Comment: By assumptions, $d >1$ and $k(f,g)=k(t)$, so condition (iii) of Theorem 15 is not satisfied (here, the degree of the field extension $k(f,g) \subseteq k(t)$ is $1 < d$). Then conditions (i) and (ii) are not satisfied-- hopefully this may imply something interesting for my question I wish to get that $\deg(f) | \deg(g)$, but I am not sure what additional conditions are required to guarantee this, so I have suggested my condition (4), but I guess it does not help much.