# Finding $a,b \in k$ such that $\gcd(f(t)-a,g(t)-b)=t$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, resultant

Let $f=f(t),g=g(t) \in k[t]$, whrer $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.

Assume that:

**(i)** $k(f,g)=k(t)$.
Therefore, there exist $P(X,Y),Q(X,Y) \in k[X,Y]$, such that 
$t=\frac{P(f,g)}{Q(f,g))}$.

**(ii)** $f=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_it^i$, $g=\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_jt^j$,
where $a_i,b_j \in k$ and $a_1b_1 \neq 0$.
Therefore, $f'(0)=a_1$, $g'(0)=b_1$, $f(0)=0$, $g(0)=0$.

By questions [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), there exist $a,b,c \in k$
such that $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=t-c$.

> When is it possible to find $a,b \in k$ such that $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=t$?
>   namely, when can we can take $c=0$?

According to the answer in [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), $c=0$ is possible, if there exist no $d \in k$ such that $Q(f(d),g(d))=0$ and $f(d)=f(c)$.
Here, $f(c)=0$, so if $d$ is another root of $f$, we must have 
$Q(0,g(d))=Q(f(d),g(d)) \neq 0$.
However, I do not know what is the form of such $Q$;
if we knew that $Q(0,g(d) \neq 0$, then we were done).

**Remark:** Here $t$ divides both $f$ and $g$, but perhaps there exist additional common divisors of $f$ and $g$. Notice that $t^2$ does not divide $f$ nor $g$,
since otherwise, $f'(0)=g'(0)=0$, but here $f'(0)=a_1 \neq 0$ and $g'(0)=b_1 \neq 0$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If such $a,b$ exist, then it must be $a=f(0)$ and $b=g(0)$.

Comment: Thank you! Please, can you explain? (So here $a=f(0)=0, b=g(0)=0$, the original $f$ and $g$).

Comment: If $t$ is a divisor of $f(t)-a$, then $a$ must be the constant term of $f(t)$; that is, $a$ must be $f(0)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, what if we replace the requirement $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=t$ by $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=1$?

Comment: That should be true for all but finitely many pairs $a,b$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, nice and easy explanation. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank you for your second answer. I guess that the explanation is somewhat similar (probably easier) to the explanation for $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=t-c$ presented in [2]?

Comment: Please, I do not understand: Shouldn't $\deg(\gcd (f-a,g-b))=0$ true for all but finitely many pairs $(a,b) \in k^2$ contradict https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c?noredirect=1&lq=1, namely, $\deg(\gcd (f-a,g-b))=1$ true for all but finitely many pairs $(a,b) \in k^2$?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding that other question. I think it says for (almost) every $c$ there exist $a,b$ such that $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=t-c$. So for (almost) every $a$ there exist $b,c$ such that $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=t-c$. But that doesn't imply that for (almost) every pair $a,b$ there exists $c$ such that $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=t-c$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. (I guess you are right).

Comment: @GerryMyerson, please, what do you think about https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404163/finding-a-b-in-k-such-that-deg-gcd-f-1-a-g-1-b-deg-gcd-f-2-a-g-2 Thank you very much!