# $f,g \in k[t]$ such that $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$ and $k(f,gt)=k(t)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory, resultant

Let $f=f(t), g=g(t) \in k[t]$ be two nonzero polynomials over a field $k$ of characteristic zero.
Assume that the following two conditions are satisfied:

**(i)** $\deg(f)=\deg(g) \geq 1$.

**(ii)** $k(f,gt)=k(t)$.

**Example:** $f=g=t^2$, indeed, $\deg(f)=\deg(g)=2$ and $k(t^2,t^3)=k(t)$.

> **Question:** Is it possible to find all such $f,g$?

**My partial answer:** It is not difficult to see that the following three families of $f,g$ are satisfying conditions **(i)** and **(ii)**:

**(1)** $\deg(f)=deg(g)=1$, namely, both are linear. Indeed, write $f=at+b, g=ct+d$.
Trivially, $at+b \in k(at+b,(ct+d)t)=k(f,gt)$, then $t \in k(f,gt)$, hence $k(f,gt)=k(t)$.

**(2)** $f=at^n+b$, $g=ct^n+d$, where $a,c \in k-\{0\}$, $b,d \in k$, $n \geq 2$ (actually, we can take $n=1$ and obtain the previous case **(1)**). Indeed, $at^n+b \in k(at^n+b,(ct^n+d)t)=k(f,gt)$,
so $t^n \in k(f,gt)$, and then $g=ct^n+d \in k(f,gt)$, and finally, $t=\frac{gt}{g} \in k(f,gt)$.

**(3)** $f=g$; this is clear.

**Remarks:**

**(a)** I excluded the case $\deg(f)=\deg(g)=0$, because in this case $f=\lambda \in k-\{0\}$, $g=\mu \in k-\{0\}$ trivially satisfy $k(f,gt)=k(\lambda,\mu t)=k(t)$.

**(b)** The resultant is relevant, since 
$\operatorname{Res}(f,gt)=\operatorname{Res}(f,g)\operatorname{Res}(f,t)$.
However, I am not assuming that $k$ is algebrically closed, so the known property that the resultant of two polynomials is zero iff they have a common root in that algebraically closed field-- is not valid here.

**(c)** Actually, the $D$-resultant is more relevant, see [Theorem 3.2](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82612218.pdf),
which implies that the $D$-resultant of $f$ and $gt$ is nonzero.

**(d)** [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c?rq=1) is also relevant, though perhaps not practical.

**(e)** Denote $\deg(f)=\deg(g)=n$. Notice that if $n \geq 2$, then by [Abhyankar-Moh-Suzuki's theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0163), necessarily $k[f,gt] \subsetneq k[t]$.
Indeed, $n=\deg(f) \nmid \deg(gt)=n+1$ and $n+1=\deg(gt) \nmid \deg(f)=n$.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: what do you mean by $k(f,g)$?

Comment: @LucasHenrique, thanks. $k(f,g)$ is the field of fractions of $k[f,g]$. Similarly, $k(f,gt)$ is the field of fractions of $k[f,gt]$.

Comment: Well maybe you should try to work out first the case of $k$ being algebraically closed and then try the general one?

Comment: @IoannisZolas, thanks. Please: (1) Could you elaborate your idea? (2) Do you think that it is possible to find all such $f,g$?

Comment: @IoannisZolas, what I know is as follows: Theorem 3.2 is true over any field, so we can apply it and get that the $D$-resultant of $f$ and $gt$ is nonzero. If we work over $\bar{k}$ (an algebraic closure of $k$), we can apply the known result to the $D$-resultan of $f$ and $gt$ and get that 'the appropriate polynomials' (not $f$ and $gt$, but those appearing in the $D$-resultant) are coprime over $\bar{k}$ and then coprime over $k$. However, I am not sure what is the connection between $f$ and $gt$ and 'the appropriate polynomials' being coprime. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\deg f, \deg h$ are coprime (which is true in your case, when $h=gt$), then $[k(t):k(f)]=\deg f$ and $[k(t):k(h)]=\deg h$ and thus $[k(t):k(f,h)]$ divides both $\deg f, \deg h$ and thus must be one. So, any choice of $f,g$ with $\deg f=\deg g$ will do.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is helpful as always.