# $f,g \in k[t]$ with $k(f,g)=k(t)$, $\deg(f)=2$ and $\deg(g)=3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory, resultant

Let $f=f(t),g=g(t) \in k[t]$, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.

Assume that the following two conditions are satisfied:

**(i)** $\deg(f)=2$ and $\deg(g)=3$.

**(ii)** $k(f,g)=k(t)$.

> **Question:** Is it possible to find a general form of such $f$ and $g$?

The above question is a special case of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684450/f-g-in-kt-such-that-degf-degg-and-kf-gt-kt) question (in the current notation,
in the linked question we have $\deg(f)=n$ and $\deg(g)=n+1$).

**An attempt for an answer:**
Write $f=t^2+at+b$ and $g=t^3+ct^2+dt+e$, where $a,b,c,d,e \in k$.
By [Theorem 3.2](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82612218.pdf), the $D$-resultant of $f$ and $g$ is nonzero.
However, I am not sure if computing the $D$-resultant and showing it is nonzero yields anything.

Another way is to apply [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c?noredirect=1&lq=1) result, and obtain that there exist $\lambda,\mu,\nu \in k$
such that $\gcd(f-\lambda,g-\mu)=t-\nu$. Again I do not see how this helps in finding a general form of $f$ and $g$.

**Remark:** By [A-M-S theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0163), $k[f,g] \subsetneq k[t]$. (Then, if I am not wrong, there exist $\lambda, \mu \in k$
such that $\deg(\gcd(f-\lambda,g-\mu)) \neq 1$).

**Edit:** A computation of the $D$-resultant of $f=t^2+at+b$ and $g=t^3+ct^2+dt+e$ (by using [Proposition 1.3](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-03/S0002-9939-97-03639-3/S0002-9939-97-03639-3.pdf)) shows that
their $D$-resultant is $s^2+as+(d-ac+a^2)$. Notice that this seems plausible, since it is independent of $b,e$ as it should be.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\deg f=2, \deg g=3$, then $k(f,g)=k(t)$ without any further hypothesis. Notice that $[k(t):k(f)]=2$ and $[k(t):k(g)]=3$ and so $[k(t):k(f.g)]$ divides both $2,3$ and so must be one.

Comment: $[k(t):k(f,g)]$

Comment: Also you can copy paste your answer in OP's other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684450/f-g-in-kt-such-that-degf-degg-and-kf-gt-kt

Comment: Thank you very much Mohan and reuns.