# Generalizing a result in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ to a result in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

Assume that $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x)$.
Then by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), there exists $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{C}$
such that
$\langle u-\alpha,v-\beta \rangle = \langle x-\gamma \rangle$,
where $\langle * \rangle$ is the ideal generated by $*$.

> Is this result can be generalized to $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

**First attempt**
Let $s,t,u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Assume that $\mathbb{C}(s,t,u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
Is it true that there exist $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$\langle s-\alpha,t-\beta,u-\gamma,v-\delta \rangle = \langle x-\epsilon_1,y-\epsilon_2 \rangle$?

**Second attempt:**
Let $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Assume that $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
Is it true that there exist $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$\langle u-\alpha,v-\beta \rangle = \langle x-\gamma,y-\delta \rangle$?

Are there counterexamples for both attempts?

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** What happens if we replace $y$ by $y^2$, namely:
Let $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Assume that $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$.
Is it true that there exist $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$\langle u-\alpha,v-\beta \rangle = \langle x-\gamma,y^2-\delta \rangle$?
It seems that this result is also true or am I missing something?

Comment: What does the angle bracket $\langle \rangle$ notation mean?

Comment: @DanielDonnelly, thank you for your comment. It means the ideal generated by the elements in that $\langle \rangle$. I will edit it now.

Comment: Adapting the proof will be tricky since sets of zeros of a polynomial or polynomials can be closed algebraic curves.

Comment: @JulesBesson, thank you. Please, do you think that the proof of the one-dimensional case can be adapted to at least one of my attempts?

Comment: Both statements are correct.

Comment: You could try replacing $\mathbb{C}$ by the field $\mathbb{C}(x)$ sometimes this works

Comment: @Mohan, thank you very much!!

Comment: @JulesBesson, thank you very much, too!! You probably hinted in your first comment that both attempts are correct? Does your second comment apply only for the second attempt?

Comment: No I'm not sure to be honest it was only an idea, @Mohan seems to know he is probably more competent than me

Comment: @JulesBesson, thanks. Mohan knew how to prove the result in the link, he mentioned that result in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Mohan, please: (1) Are there infinitely many such $\alpha,\beta,\ldots$? I think yes. (2) Is the following statement also true:  Let $u,v,w \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Assume that $\mathbb{C}(u,v,w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
Is it true that there exist $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$\langle u-\alpha,v-\beta,w-\gamma \rangle = \langle x-\delta ,y-\epsilon \rangle$? I think yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A\subset B$ be integral domains with $B$ a finitely generated $A$- algebra. Assume that the fraction fields are the same. Then  one can find an $s\neq 0$ in $A$ such that $A_s=B_s$. Now you can easily check that for any maximal ideal $M$ of $A$ not containing $s$, $MB$ is a maximal ideal of $B$. In your case, further use Hilbert Nullstellensatz to get what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understand most of your proof and it is nicer than the proof in the link. What I do not understand is why one can find $s \neq 0$ in $A$ such that $A_s=B_s$. I guess this is a well-known property for a ring extension $A \subseteq B$ as described above (integral domains, $B$ f.g. $A$-algebra, same fraction fields).

Comment: @user237522 Let $B=A[y_1,y_2,\ldots y_n]$. Fraction fields are same says $y_i=a_i/b_i$ for $a_i,b_i\in A$. Take $s=\prod b_i$.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand. Nice pure algebraic proof, as I like.

Comment: Mohan, please what about the other direction? Namely, let $u_1,\ldots,u_n \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $n \geq 2$, generate a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Then, $\mathbb{C}(u_1,\ldots,u_n)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$?

Comment: Is it possible to adjust your one-dimentional proof? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1 It seems to work here also, with the right adjustments. I will try to write the details.

Comment: Please, would you take a look at my new edit?