# $F,G,H,K \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $\mathbb{C}(F,G)=\mathbb{C}(H,K)$ imply $\langle F-a,G-b \rangle=\langle H-c,K-d \rangle$, $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory, ideals

Let $F,G,H,K \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}$.

Assume that the following fields of fractions are equal:
$\mathbb{C}(F,G)=\mathbb{C}(H,K)$.

**Claim I:** There exist $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the following ideals are equal:
$\langle F-a,G-b \rangle=\langle H-c,K-d \rangle$.

> **Question I:** Is the above **Claim I** true?

I have checked a few examples, but I do not know how to prove the claim.
Perhaps there is a counterexample?

**Examples for a positive answer:**

**(1)** $\mathbb{C}(x,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y+x^3+7x^2+5x-1)$
and $\langle x,y \rangle=\langle x,y+x^3+7x^2+5x-1+1 \rangle$.

Here $a=b=c=0, d=-1$.

**(2)** $\mathbb{C}(x,y)=\mathbb{C}(x+(x-y)^2,y+(x-y)^2)$
and $\langle x,y \rangle=\langle x+(x-y)^2,y+(x-y)^2 \rangle$.

Here $a=b=c=d=0$.

---

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4723640/generalizing-a-result-in-mathbbcx-to-a-result-in-mathbbcx-y) question is relevant; the current question is a generalization of the second statement in the quoted question, changing $x,y$ to arbitrary pair of non-constant polynomials.

The following is a generalization of the current question:

Let $F_1,\ldots,F_n,G_1,\dots,G_m \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}$.

Assume that the following fields of fractions are equal:
$\mathbb{C}(F_1,\ldots,F_n)=\mathbb{C}(G_1,\ldots,G_m)$.

**Claim II:** There exist $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the following ideals are equal:
$\langle F_1-a_1,\ldots,F_n-a_n \rangle=\langle G_1-b_1,\ldots,G_m-b_m \rangle$.

> **Question II:** Is the above **Claim II** true?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems that scalars are ok too, for example: $\mathbb{C}(x,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y,5)$ and $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle x,y,5-5 \rangle$. Here, $a_1=a_2=b_1=b_2=0$ and $b_3=5$.