# If $\mathbb{C}(u,v,x^n)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, for every $n \geq 1$, then already $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $u,v \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ (or $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, if it is easier to answer in this case).

Assume that the following condition, call it $C(n)$, is satisfied for every $n \geq 1$:
$\mathbb{C}(u,v,x^n)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

> **Question 1:** Is it true that
> $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$?

**Remarks:**

1. I excluded $C(0)$, since for $n=0$ we trivially have
   $\mathbb{C}(u,v,x^0)=\mathbb{C}(u,v,1)=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$,
   so the claim is true.
2. $u=xy, v=x$ is not a counterexample, since $\mathbb{C}(xy,x)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ with or without adding $x^n$, $n \geq 1$.
3. $u=x^2, v=y$ is not a counterexample, since $\mathbb{C}(x^2,y,x^2)=\mathbb{C}(x^2,y) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$, so the condition does not hold for $n=2$ (and also  does not hold for any even $n$).
4. Maybe using some Galois theory may help, if we further assume something on the degree of the field extension $\mathbb{C}(x,y) : \mathbb{C}(u,v)$.
   For example, further assume that $d=[\mathbb{C}(x,y) : \mathbb{C}(u,v)]=p$, $p \geq 2$ a prime number. We can think about $u=x^2,v=y$. In this case $d=2$. But, as we mentioned, $C(2m)$ does not hold for every $m \geq 1$, so those $u,v$ are not relevant for this question.
5. If we look for a counterexample, maybe we should try to find $u,v$ with $d=p \geq 2$ prime, $y \in \mathbb{C}(u,v)$ and $x^n \notin \mathbb{C}(u,v)$, for every $n \geq 1$.
   We can take $v=y$, but I have not yet found an appropriate $u$, namely, $u \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $[\mathbb{C}(x,y) : \mathbb{C}(u,y)]=2$ (or any other prime number) with $x^n \notin \mathbb{C}[u,y]$, for every $n \geq 1$, and since the extension is of prime degree, then necessarily $\mathbb{C}(u,y,x^n)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, for every $n \geq 1$.
6. Another direction is considering notions like "[factorially closed subring](https://msp.org/ant/2015/9-5/ant-v9-n5-p03-p.pdf)".
7. Perhaps one can find a proof by induction on the $y$-degree of $v$,
   with arbitrary $u$?
8. Perhaps the [Cremona group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cremona_group) may help.

Thank you very much!

---

In view of the counterexample, I would like to change my question to the following one, which I also posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453393/if-mathbbcux-y-vx-y-fx-mathbbcx-y-for-every-fx-in-mathbb), in MO:

Let $u,v \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

Assume that the following condition, call it $D(f)$, is satisfied for every $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]-\mathbb{C}$:
$\mathbb{C}(u,v,f)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

> **Question 2:** Is it true that
> $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$?

Notice that the above counterexample does not work now, since $u=x^2+x, v=y$ does not satisfy $D(x^2+x)$.

Question 2 has an answer in MO, a counterexample with $u=x+y, v=xy$.

Comment: Can you first prove your conjecture when $v=y?$

Comment: @AnneBauval, thank you for your comment!  It seems that for $v=y$, we must have $u=ax+b$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$? Because in that special case the conditions $C(n)$, $n \geq 1$, reduce to: $\mathbb{C}(u,x^n)=\mathbb{C}(x)$, for every $n \geq 1$?

Comment: No. For instance $u$ may be equal to $x+y.$

Comment: @AnneBauval, oh, you are right. thank you. So, for $v=y$, we can take $u=ax+H(y)$, for some $H(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$, $a \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Sorry, I give up, your problem is too complicated for me. Good luck!

Comment: @AnneBauval, thank you very much for your blessing! and thanks for your help. I liked your comments. Indeed it seems a good idea to begin with the case $v=y$.

Comment: How about $u=x(xy+1),v=y$?

Comment: @Zerox, thank you very much.  Could you explain? Your counterexample is for ideals, I think, not for fraction fields, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I found my example may not fit.

Comment: @Zerox, it's ok! It is always nice to get comments. Your idea is nice. It satisfies $C(1)$ and  $C(2)$ and it is interesting to ask whether it satisfies additional $C(m)$'s. As ideals, $\langle u,v \rangle = \langle x^2y+x,y \rangle=  \langle x,y \rangle$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c are relevant for the proof of the special case $v=y$, which is already not easy!

Comment: For $v=y$, we can take $u=F+Gx$, where $F,G \in \mathbb{C}[y]$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, thank you for your advice. You are right, I will do as you suggested (in a few hours).

Answer (score 1):

**A counterexample:** $u=x^2+x, v=y$. The explanation is a as follows:

1. It is clear that $\mathbb{C}(x^2+x,y) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$, so we wish to show that $C(n)$ is satisfied for every $n \geq 1$.
2. $C(n)$ says:
   $\mathbb{C}(x^2+x,y,x^n)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
   Fix any $n \geq 1$.

Since $y$ is already in $\mathbb{C}(x^2+x,y,x^n)$, it is left to show that $x \in \mathbb{C}(x^2+x,y,x^n)$ (we can forget about $y$).

**Claim:** $\mathbb(x^2+x,x^n)=\mathbb{C}(x)$.

**Proof of Claim:** Apply [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1) which says that for $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, if there exist $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$\gcd(f-a,g-b)=x-c$, then $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(x)$.

Here, it is clear that $\gcd(x^2+x,x^n)=\gcd(x(x+1),x^n)=x$, therefore $\mathbb{C}(x^2+x,x^n)=\mathbb{C}(x)$.

Concluding that $\mathbb{C}(x^2+x,y,x^n)=\mathbb{C}(x^2+x,x^n)(y)=\mathbb{C}(x)(y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, so $C(n)$ is satisfied for every $n \geq 1$.