A subfield $\mathbb{C}(u(t)) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(t)$ satisfying $\mathbb{C}(u(t),t^n)=\mathbb{C}(t)$
Let $u=u(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$, with $\deg_t(u)=d \geq 1$.
Let $R=\mathbb{C}(u(t)) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(t)$ be the subfield generated by $u$.
It is clear that $[\mathbb{C}(t):R]=d$.
For every $n \geq 1$, define $R_{n}:=R(t^n)=\mathbb{C}(u,t^n)$.
Claim: If for every $n \geq 1$, $R_n=\mathbb{C}(t)$, then $R=\mathbb{C}(t)$ (namely, $d=1$).
Remarks:

$u(t)=t^m$, for some $m \geq 2$, is impossible, since in that case we have $R_m=\mathbb{C}(t^m,t^m)=\mathbb{C}(t^m) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(t)$.
Perhaps one can prove the claim by contradiction, taking $u=t^d+c_{d-1}t^{d-1}+\cdots+c_1t+c_0$, $d \geq 2$, $c_i \in \mathbb{C}$, and then somehow finding an appropriate $n_0$ for which $R_{n_0} \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(t)$. The difficulty is in finding such $n_0$.

Any help is welcome; thank you!
Edit: In the comments I have written counterexamples I have found for every $d \geq 2$, $u(t)=t^d-t^{d-1}$.
I wonder if and how those counterexamples can be adjusted as counterexamples to $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, namely:
Let $u=u(x,y),v=v(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$ and denote $R=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$.
For every $n,m \geq 0$, not both zeros, define $R_{n,m}:=R(x^ny^m)=\mathbb{C}(u,v,x^ny^m)$.
Claim: If for every $n,m \geq 0$, not both zeros, $R_{n,m}=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, then $R=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
Maybe taking someting similar to $u=x^ny^m-x^{n-1}y^{m-1}$ and an appropriate $v$ would yield a counterexample? Or maybe the two-dimensional claim can be proved? Please see this question, which I do not fully understand its answer.
This question is also relevant.

Notice that by the following question we know that for every $n \geq 1$ there exist $a_n,b_n,c_n \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\gcd(u(t)-a_n,t^n-b_n)=t-c_n$, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c?rq=1

What about $u(t)=t^2-t$? maybe a counterexample?

We see that for every $n \geq 1$, $\gcd(t^2-t,t^n-1)=t-1$, hence $\mathbb{C}(t^2-t,t^n)=\mathbb{C}(t)$, by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Given $u(t)=t^3-t^2=t^2(t-1)$, for every $n \geq 1$ we have $\gcd(t^3-t^2,t^n-1)=t-1$, so $\mathbb{C}(t^2-t^2,t^n)=\mathbb{C}(t)$ and we see that in general $u(t)=t^d-t^{d-1}$ is a counterexample, of every degree $d \geq 2$.

The following is not a counterexample for the two-dimensional case: $u=x^3-x^2$, $v=y$, because, for example, $R_{0,1}=\mathbb{C}(x^3-x^2,y,y) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
