If for every $n \geq 1$, $k(f(t),g(t),t^n)=k(t)$, then $k(f(t),g(t))=k(t)$?
Let $f=f(t),g=g(t) \in k(t)$, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero and $\deg_t(f),\deg_t(g) \geq 1$.
Assume that for every $n \geq 1$ we have $k(f(t),g(t),t^n)=k(t)$, where $k(f(t),g(t),t^n)$ means the field generated over $k$ by $\{f,g,t^n\}$.

Question: Is it true that $k(f(t),g(t))=k(t)$?


Notice that the counterexample to this question, where we change there the condition from $x^n$ to $y^n$, does not hold here; indeed, there $u=u(x,y)=x^2+x$ and $v=v(x,y)=y$, so if take $k=\mathbb{C}(x)$, $y=t$, then $u$ and $v$ become $f(t) \in k$ and $g(t)=t$, so $\deg_t(f)=0$. Or we can remove the requirement on the degrees of $f$ and $g$, $\deg_t(f),\deg_t(g) \geq 1$, hence this example does not contradict our claim, since $k(f,g)=k(t)$.
(Perhaps the requirement on the degrees of $f$ and $g$ should be: at least one of $\{\deg_t(f),\deg_t(g)\}$ is $\geq 1$).

We may try to apply this result or actually, it has a generalized version that says that if $k(f,g,h)=k(t)$, then $\langle f-a,g-b,h-c \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $k[t]$, for some $a,b,c \in k$.
Then there exist $a_n,b_n,c_n \in k$ such that $\langle f-a_n,g-b_n,t^n-c_n \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $k[t]$. Now, $\langle f-a_n,g-b_n,t^n-c_n \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $k[t]$, namely, $\langle f-a_n,g-b_n,t^n-c_n \rangle =\langle t-d_n \rangle$ for some $d_n \in k$, therefore $\{f-a_n,g-b_n,t^n-c_n\}$ has exactly one common zero $d_n$. The probelm is that $f-a_n$ and $g-b_n$ may have more than one common zero $d_n$, and moreover $f-a$ and $g-b$ may have more than one common zero for every $a,b \in k$, so $k(f,g) \subsetneq k(t)$.


Thank you very much for any help.
Edit: According to my comments, the above question has a negative answer, so I would like to change it to the following question:
What are the general forms of $h=h(t)$ such that $\mathbb{C}(h,t^n)=\mathbb{C}(t)$.
Two possible forms are:
(1) $h=t^m+at+b$, $0 \neq a,b \in k$.
(2) $h=t^m+at^{m-1}$, $0 \neq a \in k$.

Our assumption: "For every $n \geq 1$, $k(f,g,t^n)=k(t)$" implies that for every $n \geq 1$, there exist $a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n \in k$ such that $\langle f-a_n,g-b_n,t^n-c_n \rangle=\langle t-d_n\rangle$.

Of course, $f=t^2, g=t^4$, for which $k(t^2,t^4)=k(t^2) \subsetneq k(t)$ is not a counterexample, since those $f$ and $g$ do not satisfy $P_2$, where $P_2$ says: "for $n=2$, $k(f,g,t^2)=k(t)$".

Another result that may help is Lüroth theorem: A field $L$, $k \subset L \subset k(t)$ containing a nonconstant polynomial over $k$ is equal to $k(h)$ for some $h \in k[t]$. More precisely, Lüroth proved that such $h \in k(t)$ and E. Noether proved that actually $h \in k[t]$. So here $k(f,g)=k(h)$, for some $h \in k[t]$. Then $P_n$ says that $k(h,t^n)=k(f,g,t^n)=k(t)$, for every $n \geq 1$.

What about $h=t^2+t$? a counterexample? We have $k(t^2+t,t^n)=k(t)$ for every $n \geq 1$ (by the criterion mentioned in the question, concerning the ideals).

What about $h=t^m+t$? Again such $h$ is a counterexample.

Is $h=t^m+at+b$, $0 \neq a,b \in k$, the only counterexample, or there are more?

Another family of counterexamples is $h=t^m+t^{m-1}$, as was explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4933002/a-subfield-mathbbcut-subseteq-mathbbct-satisfying-mathbbcut#comment10542197_4933002
