# When $\mathbb{C}(f(t),g(t))=\mathbb{C}(t)$ implies that $\mathbb{C}[f(t),g(t)]=\mathbb{C}[t]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $f=f(t), g=g(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$.

Assume that:

**(1)** $\deg(f) \geq 2,\deg(g) \geq 2$.

**(2)** $\mathbb{C}(f(t),g(t))=\mathbb{C}(t)$.

**(3)** The set of zeros of $f$, $S_f$, equals the set of zeros of $g$,
$S_g$; denote $S_f=S_g=\{c_1,\ldots,c_m\}$.

**(4)** $\langle f'(t),g'(t) \rangle = \mathbb{C}[t]$ (namely, the ideal generated by $f'$ and $g'$ is the unit ideal).

Now, **(4)**  implies that $f'$ and $g'$ do not have a common zero (there is no need to apply [Hilbert's weak Nullstellensatz](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/hilberts-nullstellensatz/)), so from **(3)** we obtain that:

$f(t)=\lambda(t-c_1)^{d_1}\cdots(t-c_l)^{d_l}(t-c_{l+1})^{d_{l+1}}\cdots(t-c_m)^{d_m}$,

$g(t)=\mu(t-c_1)^{e_1}\cdots(t-c_l)^{e_l}(t-c_{l+1})^{e_{l+1}}\cdots(t-c_m)^{e_m}$,

where $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$,

and $d_i,e_i \geq 1$ are such that if $d_i \geq 2$ then $e_i=1$ and vice versa (= if $e_i \geq 2$ then $d_i=1$).

The reason is as follows: If, for example, $d_1 \geq 2$ then $c_1$ is also a zero of $f'(t)$, and if $e_1 \geq 2$ then $c_1$ would also be a zero of $g'(t)$, but then $c_1$ would be a common zero of $f'(t)$ and $g'(t)$, contrary to assumption **(4)**.

> Is it true that necessarily $\mathbb{C}[f(t),g(t)]=\mathbb{C}[t]$? Or is there a counterexample?

Notice that $f(t)=t^2$, $g(t)=t^3$ is not a counterexample, since conditions **(1)**, **(2)**, **(3)** are satisfied, but condition **(4)** is not satisfied.

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830054/characterizing-f-and-g-such-that-deg-gcdf-g-geq-2?rq=1) question.

**Edit:** After receivig a counterexample, do you think that there exists an additional (not too strong) condition that will guarantee that $\mathbb{C}[f(t),g(t)]=\mathbb{C}[t]$? There is a [nice condition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.3064.pdf) which says that $f'(t),g'(t) \in \mathbb{C}[f(t),g(t)]$, so the fifth condition, together with the former four conditions, should imply that $f'(t),g'(t) \in \mathbb{C}[f,g]$.

A 'plausible' fifth condition: **(5)** $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are [separable polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial).
In that case we must have: $d_i=e_i=1$ for every $1 \leq i \leq m$. Therefore, $f(t)=g(t)$, so from **(2)** we get that $\mathbb{C}(f(t))= \mathbb{C}(f(t),g(t))=\mathbb{C}(t)$, hence $\deg(f)=1$ which contradicts condition **(1)**... Therefore, if we omit condition **(1)** and add condition **(5)**, we obtain that $\mathbb{C}[f(t),g(t)]=\mathbb{C}[t]$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: $f(t) = (t+1)^2t,g(t) = t^2(t+1)$ ?

Comment: Thank you. How to show that $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(t)$? Should I apply https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1?

Comment: $f(t)/g(t) = ?$

Comment: Nice; easier than I thought. (The argument that I have suggested also works, but your argument is easier). Please, do you think that there is an additional condition that necessarily implies that $\mathbb{C}[f,g]=\mathbb{C}[t]$?