# Computing subresultants in WolframAlpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha, computer-algebra-systems, resultant

Let $f(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_m)$
and $g(x)=(x-a_{m+1})(x-a_{m+2})\cdots(x-a_n)$,
where $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, $m < n$, $a_i \in F$, $F$ is a field of characteristic zero (for example, $k \in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$).
Let $\lambda,\mu \in F$.

> How to compute the [subresultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Subresultants) of $f(x)-\lambda$ and $g(x)-\mu$?

If, for example, $m=2$ and $n=4$, then I have succeeded to compute it using $a,b,c,d$:

subresultants [(x-a)(x-b) -\lambda, (x-c)(x-d) - \mu].

But it seems that beyond $a,b,c,d,e$ it is not possible? Or just because I have written $f,g$ (which probably denotes functions). Writing the $a_i$'s does not work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking here; but note that WolframAlpha will happily treat expressions like `a[1]`, `a[2]`, ... the same way it treats undefined constants like `a`, `b`, .... For example, the expression `Product[ x-a[j] , {j, 1, m} ]` will generate the general monic degree-$m$ polynomial $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_m)$.

Comment: I don't have any trouble w/ command like `Subresultants[(x-a)*(x-b)*(x-c)-\lambda,(x-d)*(x-e)*(x-f)-\mu,x]`.

Comment: Thank you, @GregMartin. Sorry for not being clear. However, you understood what I meant.

Comment: @achillehui, thank you. Perhaps the problem was that I have not used *

Comment: Something like `Subresultants[Product[x-a[i],{i,1,2}]-\lambda,Product[x-b[j],{j,1,3}]-\mu,x]`. Replacing upper bound of $i$ by $3$ doesn't work. Replacing upper bound of $j$ to $4$ work and to $5$ doesn't work. It looks like an arbitrary limit WA imposed on its online computational capacity. In order words, a hint to suggest you to use Mathematica instead.

Comment: @achillehui, your example is very helpful, thank you. I have tried: Subresultants $(x-a[1])(x-a[2])(x-a[3])-\lambda, (x-b[1])(x-b[2])(x-b[3])-\mu$, but got an error.. as you mention. Is it possible to compute this in Mathematica?

Comment: @user237522 Sorry, I don't have access to Mathematica.

Comment: @achillehui, ok, thank you for your help. Please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188570/computing-subresultants/188571?noredirect=1#comment491663_188571

Comment: @achillehui Ok, I ran the code snippet from your comment yesterday on my copy of Mathematica, and taking `{i,1,3}` and `{j,1,5}` simultaneously took about 20 seconds on my laptop. So I agree with you—probably an imposed limit of WA.