# When $\mathbb{C}(f(t),g(t))=\mathbb{C}(t)$ imply that there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\deg(\gcd(f(t)-a,g(t)-b))=2$?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, resultant

Assume that $f=f(t),g=g(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ satisfy the following two conditions:

**(1)** $\deg(f) \geq 2$ and $\deg(g) \geq 2$.

**(2)** $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(t)$.

After asking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx) and then [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c) and getting nice answers, I would like to ask the following question:

> What additional conditions on $f$ and $g$ are required in order to guarantee the existence of $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\deg(\gcd(f-a,g-b))=2$?

Notice that if $f=t^2$ and $g=t^2-2t$, then there are no such $a,b$.

**A plausible(?) additional condition:** What if we assume, in addition, that all monomials of degrees $\geq 1$ in $f$ and $g$ have non-zero coefficients?

**Remarks:** 
**(1)** Take $f=t^2, g=t^3$. For $a=b=0$ we have 
$\deg(\gcd(f-a,g-b))=\deg(\gcd(t^2-0,t^3-0))=\deg(\gcd(t^2,t^3))=\deg(t^2)=2$.
If I am not wrong, $a=b=0$ is the only option for $\deg(\gcd(f-a,g-b))=2$.

If $(a,b) \neq (0,0)$, then $\deg(\gcd(f-a,g-b)) \in \{0,1\}$.

Therefore, it is not reasonable to expect the existence of infinitely many such $(a,b)$. In contrast to the case $\deg(\gcd(f-a,g-b))=1$, where we had infinitely many such $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.

**(2)** Observe that if $\deg(\gcd(f-a,g-b))=2$, and if it happens that $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=(t-c)^2$ for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$, then $\deg(\gcd(f',g'))\geq 1$ 
(since $t-c$ divides $\gcd(f',g')$).

Then the ideal in $k[t]$ generated by $f',g'$ 
cannot equal $k[t]$, since otherwise there would exist $u,v \in k[t]$
such that $1=uf'+vg'= u(t-c)F+v(t-c)G$, which is impossible.
($F$ is such that $f'=(t-c)F$ and $G$ is such that $g'=(t-c)G$).

> We could be more precise and require either $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=(t-c)^2$
>   or $\gcd(f-a,g-b)=(t-c)(t-d)$, where $c,d \in \mathbb{C}$ with $d \neq c$;
>   both cases are interesting for me.

Please see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830054/characterizing-f-and-g-such-that-deg-gcdf-g-geq-2?rq=1) question and its nice answer; so a necessary and sufficient condition is that $s_0=s_1=0$ and $s_2 \neq 0$, and then $s_2=\gcd(f-a,g-b)$. However, it seems quite difficult to compute $s_0,s_1,s_2$ for high degree $f$ and $g$.

Is there something interesting that we can say about the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ that will guarantee $s_0=s_1=0, s_2 \neq 0$?
In particular, is the plausible condition I have mentioned above (all coefficients of monomials of degrees $geq 1$ are non-zero) may help?

Of course, my condition is not necessary, since for $f=t^3-4t$, $g=t^2+1$,
$t$ does not appear in $g$, but still for $a=0,b=5$ we have:
$f-0=t^3-4t=t(t^2-4)$ and $g-5=t^2+1-5=t^2-4$, so $\gcd(f-0,g-5)=t^2-4$.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: $f(t)-f(a),g(t)-g(a)$ have a common root at $a$. You are asking if for some $a$ they have another common root. The answer is no : try with $f(t) = t^2,g(t) = t^2+t$

$f(t)-f(a) = (t-a)(t+a), g(t)-g(a) = t^2+t-a^2-a=(t-a)(t+a+1)$

Comment: @reuns, thank you. I have mentioned your example in my question ("Notice that if $f=t^2$ and $g=t^2-2t$, then there are no such $a,b$"). This is why I asked for additional conditions, in order to avoid such cases. But thank you for emphasizing this (perhaps other MSE users have not noticed that line).

Comment: Let $F = t^3+at^2+bt+c, G=t^3+At^2+Bt+C$ then $F-G = (a-A)t^2+(b-B)t+(c-C)$ ,$ F - \frac{t}{a-A} (F-G)= t^3+at^2+bt+c-(t^3+\frac{b-B}{A-a}t^2+\frac{c-C}{a-A}t)=(a-\frac{b-B}{A-a})t^2+(b-\frac{c-C}{A-a})t+c$, continuing this way you can compute the $\gcd$ of the generic cubic polynomials and obtain a rational thus algebraic equation for the coefficients of the cubic polynomials satisfying your problem.

Comment: @reuns, please, do you mean that for 'general' $F,G$ (with $\min(\deg(F),\deg(G) \geq 3$?), it is possible to find appropriate coefficients such that the gcd of $F$ and $G$ has degree $2$? Or you just deal with $\deg(F)=\deg(G)=3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\mathbb{C}(f(t),g(t))=\mathbb{C}(t)$ condition means the polynomials are coprime, if they are not it suffices to replace $f(t)$ by $f(t)+c$, so this is not really a problem.

> Thus we are in the following situation : $f(t)-f(\alpha),\ g(t)-g(\alpha)$ have a common root at $\alpha$ and you are asking if for some $\alpha$ they have another common root.

- With $f(t) = t^2, g(t) = t^2+t$ the answer is no.
- The case of cubic polynomials. Wlog we can assume they are monic, shifting $t$ to $t+\alpha$ and substracting $f(0),g(0)$ we obtain the generic monic cubic polynomials with a common root at $0$ : $F(t) = t^3+at^2+bt, G(t)=t^3+At^2+Bt$. $$\gcd(t^2+at+b,t^2+At+B) = \gcd(t^2+at+b,(A-a)t+(B-b))$$
  The $\gcd$ is not $1$ iff $(A-a)=(B-b) = 0$ or $(\frac{B-b}{a-A})^2+a (\frac{B-b}{a-A}) + b = 0$. Whence

  > Given two cubic  polynomials $f(t),g(t)$, there exists $\alpha$ such that $\gcd(f(t)-f(\alpha),g(t)-g(\alpha))$ is of degree $2$ iff $$f(t) = r((t+\alpha)^3+a(t+\alpha)^2+b(t+\alpha)+c), \\ g(t) = s((t+\alpha)^3+A(t+\alpha)^2+B(t+\alpha)+C), \\ A-a \ne 0, \quad (B-b)^2 + a (B-b)(a-A)+b(a-A)^2 = 0$$
- For higher degrees there are similar algebraic equations defining the polynomials satisfying your problem.

Comment: If I am not wrong, in your first lines you meant that we can assume that $f,g$ have common factor of degree one (otherwise, we take $f-a,g-b$ as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), and then we look for a second common factor.

Comment: (1) How to adjust your answer to the case $\deg(\gcd(f-a,g-b)) \geq 2$ (instead of $\deg(\gcd(f-a,g-b)) = 2$). (2) Is your answer essentially the same as the following answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830054/characterizing-f-and-g-such-that-deg-gcdf-g-geq-2?noredirect=1&lq=1?