# Two generators of $\mathbb{C}(t)$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $F=F(t),G=G(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$.

According to the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1) question (see also [i](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042016/why-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-implies-that-gcdft-a-gt-b-t-c) and [ii](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3334310/when-mathbbcft-gt-mathbbct-imply-that-there-exist-a-b-in-math)):
$\mathbb{C}(F,G)=\mathbb{C}(t)$ if and only if there exist $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$
such that $\gcd(F-a,G-b)=t-c$.

Now assume that $F=fh, G=gh$. where $f,g,h$ are separable (have distinct roots in $\mathbb{C}$) with
$h=\gcd(F,G)$ (so $\gcd(f,g)=1$), and $\deg(h) \geq 2$.

If $\mathbb{C}(F,G)=\mathbb{C}(t)$, is it possible to find a general form of such $F,G$?

I am not sure what is the answer I am looking for, but I think I prefer an answer not involving resultants (or more precisely, subresultants, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830054/characterizing-f-and-g-such-that-deg-gcdf-g-geq-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) question and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Subresultants)).

Any ideas are welcome!

Now also aksed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369904/two-generators-of-mathbbct).