# Special cases when $\deg(\gcd(f,g)) \in \{0,1\}$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.

Let $f=f(t), g=g(t) \in k[t]$ and assume that $\deg(f)=dn$, $\deg(g)=dm$,
where $d=\gcd(\deg(f),\deg(g)) \geq 2$, $\gcd(n,m)=1$ and $n < m$.

Then we can write $f=\sum_{i=0}^{dn}a_it^i$ and $g=\sum_{j=0}^{dm}b_jt^j$,
with $a_i,b_j \in k$, $a_{dn} \neq 0$, $b_{dm} \neq 0$.
*Further assume* that $a_{dn-1}=b_{dm-1}=0$.

**Remark:** I am not sure if the assumption that $\deg(f)=dn$ and $\deg(g)=dm$ is important or not. However, I wish to assume that 
the 'second leading coefficients' of $f$ and $g$ are zeros,
namely, $a_{\deg(f)-1}=b_{\deg(g)-1}=0$.

> What additional conditions are required in order to guarantee that
>   $\deg(\gcd(f,g)) \in \{0,1\}$?

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830054/characterizing-f-and-g-such-that-deg-gcdf-g-geq-2?rq=1), we need one of the following cases to happen:
**(i)** $s_0 \neq 0$ (for the case $\deg(\gcd(f,g)) =0$).
**(ii)** $s_0= 0$ and $s_1 \neq 0$ (for the case $\deg(\gcd(f,g)) =1$).

In other words, we wish to show that it is not possible to have $s_0=s_1=0$ (which is equivalent to $\deg(\gcd(f,g)) \geq 2$).

Actually, I wish to find the 'exact' form of $s_0$ and $s_1$ (these are expressions in $a_i, b_j$), and then I can see when $s_0=s_1=0$ is not possible. Unfortunately, I am afraid that for arbitrary $f$ and $g$,
$s_0$ and $s_1$ are very complicated expressions in $a_i,b_j$,
so it will be difficult to determine whether $s_0=s_1=0$ or not.
Are there additional conditions on the coefficients or degrees that would help? (Is my condition $a_{\deg(f)-1}=b_{\deg(g)-1}=0$ helpful?).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that $\deg(\gcd(f,g))=0$ if and only if $R(f,g)=0$, where $R$ denotes the resultant. The resultant is generally quite easy to compute. Also, are you interested in fields of characteristic zero in general, or in specific fields? For example finite extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$ or subfields of $\Bbb{C}$? Because for many such fields much more can be said.

Comment: @Servaes, thank you for your comment. (1) I am (slightly) familiar with the resultant $R=s_0$. What about $s_1$? (2) I am curious about "Because for many such fields much more can be said"; please, could you elaborate? I do not mind to assume that $k$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ or a finite field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. What if $k$ is not a field but $\mathbb{Z}$?.

Comment: @Servaes. please, could you elaborate about the ideas in your comment? (I do not see why the resultant is easy to compute for arbitrary $f$ and $g$; what am I missing?)