# Which $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ satisfy $\mathbb{C}(fy,gy)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, field-theory

Let $f=f(x,y), g=g(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

> Which $f,g$ satisfy $\mathbb{C}(fy,gy)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$?

Examples:

**(1)** $f=2x$, $g=1-2x$. It is easy to see that
$\mathbb{C}(2xy,(1-2x)y)=\mathbb{C}(2xy,y-2xy)=\mathbb{C}(2xy,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

**(2)** $f=x$, $g=xy$.

Attempts to generalize the two examples:

**(1)** $af+bg \in \mathbb{C}[x]-\{0\}$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, similarly to example **(1)**. But if $f=x^2$ and $g=x^4$, then this does not work since $\mathbb{C}(x^2y,x^4y)=\mathbb{C}(x^2,y)$. So perhaps we should require $af+bg \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$? This will imply that $\mathbb{C}(fy,gy) \ni afy+bgy=y(af+bg)=\lambda y$, and then $f,g \in \mathbb{C}(fy,gy)$, which still does not guarantee that $x \in \mathbb{C}(fy,gy)$.

**(2)** The following seems to be a false claim: $f$ and $g$ themselves already generate $\mathbb{C}$, namely: $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$; although in example **(2)** it works, but in other cases it may not work.

**Edit:** After receiving a comment that the resultant may be relevant, I add the following links: [Theorem 2.1](http://hub.hku.hk/bitstream/10722/156137/1/content.pdf?accept=1) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1).

If I am not wrong, the criterion in the second link implies that, in our case:
If $\gcd(f,g)=1$, considering $f,g \in (\mathbb{C}(x))[y]$, then $\mathbb{C}(x)(fy,gy)=(\mathbb{C}(x))(y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I’m a bit confused. In the second of your “attempts”: what does “$fy$” mean? Isn’t $\,f$ an expression in $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I meant: "namely, $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$". My mistake. I will correct this now.

Comment: The resultant seems relevant here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I do know that for two polynomials $F,G \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, we have: $\mathbb{C}(F,G)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ if and only if the d-resultant of $F$ and $G$ is a non-zero polynomial (if it happens to be a scalar, then  $\mathbb{C}[F,G]=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$). But the problem is that I do not see how to calculate the d-resultant of two arbitrary $fy$ and $gy$; but perhaps I am missing something, and the 'specific' $fy$ and $gy$ may yield something interesting.

Comment: Actually, I was not accurate in my above comment, since the criterion I meant to mention deals with one variable polynomials: $\mathbb{C}(u(t),v(t))=\mathbb{C}(t)$  if and only if the d-resultant of $u(t),v(t)$ is a non-zero polynomial. It is possible to adjust that criterion to our $fy$ and $gy$, thought of as polynomials in one variable $y$ over $\mathbb{C}(x)$.

Comment: @Servaes, please, if you could elaborate your idea (in a comment or in an answer). Thanks.

Comment: Just a hunch, haven't chased it down, but here's the relevant [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) in case you're not familiar with the resultant.

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar with resultants and d-resultants, but for now I do not see more that what I have added in the edit (and in the comments) of my question.