# When $\mathbb{C}[u,v]$ is a UFD, for special $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[t]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains, involutions

Let $f=f(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ be a non-scalar polynomial.
Write $f=a_{2n}t^{2n}+a_{2n-1}t^{2n-1}+\cdots+a_2t^2+a_1t+a_0$,
where $a_j \in \mathbb{C}$.

The map $\iota: t \mapsto -t$ is an involution on $\mathbb{C}[t]$, namely, a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra automorphism of degree two.

Denote the set of symmetric elements w.r.t. $\iota$ by $S$ and 
the set of skew-symmetric elements w.r.t. $\iota$ by $K$.
Notice that even polynomials are symmetric elements w.r.t. $\iota$,
while odd polynomials are skew-symmetric elements w.r.t. $\iota$.

Write $f=s+k$, where $s \in S$ and $k \in K$.

Clearly, $\mathbb{C}[f] \subseteq \mathbb{C}[t]$ is a UFD ($\mathbb{C}[f]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t]$).

> **Question 1:** Is it possible to find a general form of $f$ such that $R_{f}:=\mathbb{C}[s,k]$ is a UFD?

**Partial answer:** In the following four cases $R_{f}$ is a UFD:

**(i)** $k=0$, so $f=s \in S$, and then $R_{f}=\mathbb{C}[s,0]=\mathbb{C}[s] \cong \mathbb{C}[t]$.

**(ii)** $s=0$, so $f=k \in K$, and then $R_{f}=\mathbb{C}[0,k]=\mathbb{C}[k] \cong \mathbb{C}[t]$.

**(iii)** $k=t$, so $R_{f}=\mathbb{C}[s,t]=\mathbb{C}[t]$.

**(iv)** $s=k^{2m}$ for some $m$,
so $R_{f}=\mathbb{C}[k^{2m},k]=\mathbb{C}[k] \cong \mathbb{C}[t]$.
For example, $s=\lambda t^6$, $k=\mu t^3$, so $R_{f}=\mathbb{C}[\lambda t^6,\mu t^3]=\mathbb{C}[t^3] \cong \mathbb{C}[t]$.

> **Question 1':** Are there additional cases?

**Non-example:** For $f=t^3+t^2$, $R_{f}=\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$ is not a UFD, as
$t^2t^2t^2=t^3t^3$ shows.

**Remark:** [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916181/is-a-subalgebra-of-mathbbcx-1-ldots-x-n-of-krull-dimension-one-isomorph) question is relevant, especially the comments of Mohan and user26857,
saying the following: "If $R$ is Noetherian, integrally closed and dimension one $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebra of the polynomial ring, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t]$". Therefore, here, if $R_{f}$ is not a UFD, then it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t]$, hence $R_{f}$ is not integrally closed.

On the other hand, if $R_{f}$ is integrally closed, then it equals its integral closure, which is of the form $\mathbb{C}[g]$ for some $g \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ (= this result appears in the paper of Paul Eakin "A note on finite dimensional subrings of polynomial rings"). Therefore, $R_{f}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t]$, hence it is a UFD.

Summarizing, my questions 1 and 1' are equivalent to the following question:

> **Question 1'':** Let $s \in S$ (= even polynomials), $k \in K$ (= odd polynomials). Is it possible to find general forms of $s$ and $k$ such that $R_{s+k}=\mathbb{C}[s,k]$ is integrally closed? (Are cases **(i)**, **(ii)** and **(iii)** the only ones?).

**Important remark to question 1'':** [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808373/for-which-f-g-in-kt-kf-g-is-integrally-closed) question and its answer are highly relevant.

---

> **Question 2:** I guess that questions 1 and 1' are not too difficult (perhaps some algebraic geometry is needed?),
>   so what if we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by an arbitrary UFD $D$?

Any comments are welcome! Thank you.