# A variation on Keller's theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory, automorphism-group

Recall:

**(1)** Given $A,B \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ we have: $\{A,B\}$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $\operatorname{Jac}(A,B) \neq 0$.

**(2)** By definition, a Jacobian pair is a pair $C,D \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ satisfying $\operatorname{Jac}(C,D) \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

**(3)** Keller's theorem ([Theorem 2.1(b)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183549636)) says the following: Let $C,D \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be a jacobian pair. If $\mathbb{C}(C,D)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, then
$\mathbb{C}[C,D]=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

> Let $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be two algebraically independent elements over $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $\operatorname{Jac}(u,v) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}$, so $\{u,v\}$ is not a Jacobian pair. Assume that $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
>   Is it true that necessarily $u=x,v=xy$ or $u=y,v=xy$ (or vice versa)?

I have not succeeded to find other examples, but perhaps I am missing something.

In view of Mohan's comment, I wish to change my question to:

> What can be said about such $u,v$? (some kind of a general form?).

Please also see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346808/special-elements-of-the-cremona-group?noredirect=1&lq=1) question and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253481/finding-all-automorphisms-of-mathbbcx-y) question.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: Wouldn't changing by automorphisms work too, for example? Take $u=x+y^2, v=xy+y^3$. I am sure there are many more which are not coming from automorphisms of the polynomial ring.

Comment: @Mohan, thank you very much! Nice counterexample. In general, is it true that necessarily $y=\frac{u}{v}$ or $x=\frac{u}{v}$ (or vice versa)? In your example, $y=\frac{v}{u}$.

Comment: @Mohan, of course, your criterion appearing in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1 can be applied here, thinking of $u,v \in k(y)[x]$ or $u,v \in k(x)[y]$. In your example, if we think of  $u,v \in k(y)[x]$, then each is of degree one, and actually $v=yu$. (However, this does not help in finding the forms of $u$ and $v$, as you have mentioned there).