# When $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(f',g')=\mathbb{C}(t)$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $f=f(t),g=g(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ be two non-constant polynomials with $\deg(f)=n$, $\deg(g)=m$.
Denote the first derivative of $f,g$ by $f',g'$, 
and the second derivative of $f,g$ by $f'',g''$, respectively.

Assume that the following three conditions are satisfied:

**(i)** $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(t)$, namely, the field of fractions of $\mathbb{C}[f,g]$ equals the field of fractions of $\mathbb{C}[t]$.

**(ii)** $\mathbb{C}(f',g')=\mathbb{C}(t)$, namely, the field of fractions of $\mathbb{C}[f',g']$ equals the field of fractions of $\mathbb{C}[t]$.

**(iii)** $\langle f'',g'' \rangle= \langle 1 \rangle= \mathbb{C}[t]$, namely, the ideal in $\mathbb{C}[t]$ generated by $f'',g''$, is the unit ideal.

> Is it possible to find the 'exact' form of such $f,g$ or find a restriction on $n,m$?

**Non-example:** $f=t^4,g=t^3$. Then $f'=4t^3,g'=3t^2$, $f''=12t^2, g''=6t$; conditions **(i)** and **(ii)** are satisfied: $\mathbb{C}(t)=\mathbb{C}(t^4,t^3)=\mathbb{C}(4t^3,3t^2)$, while condition **(iii)** is not satisfied.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1) question may be relevant; its answer says the following:
$\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(t)$ if and only if there exist $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\gcd(u-a,v-b)=t-c$.

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: Why not $f = \frac{1}{2} t^2$, $g = t$ to replace your non-example with an example?

Comment: @EricTowers, nice, thank you! Is this example the 'only' example possible? Namely, with $n =2$? (Sorry for not being clear in my question. I wished to obtain an answer which restricts $n$ or $m$, or something similar).

Comment: Working backwards through the conditions to find a low degree example was pretty easy, but that doesn't mean that I have insight into solving the general problem.

Comment: @EricTowers, oh I see, thank you. If you will have any insights concerning the general problem, please let me know.