# $f,g \in k[t]$ satisfying several conditions

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, resultant

Let $f=f(t), g=g(t) \in k[t]$, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
Assume that:

**(i)** $k(f,g)=k(t)$.

**(ii)** $k(f',g')=k(t)$.

**(iii)** $\langle f'',g'' \rangle = k[t]$.

> Is it true that **(iv)** $k[f',g']=k[t]$? I guess that there exists a counterexample..

For now I have checked the following examples:

**(1)** $f=t^4, g=t^3$. So $f'=4t^3, g'=3t^2$, and $f''=12t^2, g''=6t$.
Conditions **(i)** and **(ii)** are satisfied.
Condition **(iii)** is not satisfied.
**(iv)** does not hold: $k[f',g']=k[t^2] \subsetneq k[t]$.

**(2)** $f=t^3-t, g=t^3-4t$. So $f'=3t^2-1, g'=3t^2-4$, and $f''=6t, g''=6t$.
Condition **(i)** is satisfied.
Conditions **(ii)** and **(iii)** are not satisfied.
**(iv)** does not hold: $k[f',g']=k[t^2] \subsetneq k[t]$.

**(3)** $f=t^3-5t^2+6t=t(t^2-5t+6)=t(t-2)(t-3)$,
$g=t^3-t=t(t^2-1)=t(t-1)(t+1)$.
All three conditions are satisfied, and also the fourh condition.
The difficult thing is to show that condition **(i)** is satisfied, and this is immediate by the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?noredirect=1&lq=1) question.

But this of course does not prove anything generally..

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** Perhaps the following is a counterexample:
$f=t^{10}+t^2$, $g=t^5$. It is not sifficult to check that the three conditions are satisfied (condition **(ii)** holds by the answer to the quoted question in **(3)**). What about the fourth condition? Is it true or false that $k[10t^9+2t,5t^4] = k[t]$? I suspect that this is false. I should apply [Theorem 2.1](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-03/S0002-9939-97-03639-3/S0002-9939-97-03639-3.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Take $f=\frac{t^4}{4}-\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{t^2}{2}$, $g=\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^2}{2}$.

Then $\langle f’’,\,g’’\rangle=\langle 3t^2-2t+1,\,2t-1\rangle=k[t]$.

Moreover, $f’+g’=t^3$ so that $t^3 \in k(f’,g’)$, and hence $t^3,t^2-t \in k(f’,g’)$. So $t^4+t^2=(t^2-t)^2+2t^3 \in k(f’,g’)$, thus $t^4+t=t(t^3+1) \in k(f’,g’)$. As $t^3+1 \in k(f’,g’)$, $k(f’,g’)=t$.

Also, $\langle f’,\,g’\rangle=\langle t^3-t^2+t,\,t^2-t\rangle \subset tk[t]$.

Finally, let $K=k(f,g)$, then $t^4=4(f+g) \in K$. Therefore, $t^{-4}g^2=\left(\frac{t^2}{9}-\frac{t}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right) \in K$, thus $t^2-3t \in K$. We already know $2t^3-3t^2 \in K$, so that $2t^3-9t \in K$.
But $(2t^3-9t)^2=4t^6+81t^2-36t^4$ so that $4t^6+81t^2=t^2(4t^4+81) \in K$. As $t^4 \in K$, $t^2 \in K$. Since $g \in K$, $t^3 \in K$ and thus $K=k(t)$.

Comment: Nice counterexample, thank you! Do you think that there exists an additional mild condition that will guarantee that $k[f',g']=k[t]$?

Comment: Perhaps something with the degrees of $f$ and $g$? By A-M-S theorem, it is necessary (for (iv) to be satisfied) that $\deg(f) | deg(g)$, or vice versa; this may still not be enough, as my last example (in the edit) probably shows.

Comment: Perhaps an additional (sufficient but not necessary) condition that will guarantee $k[f',g']=k[t]$ is: $\langle f',g' \rangle=k[t]$?

Comment: If I am not wrong, this last additional condition $\langle f',g' \rangle=k[t]$ almost yields a contradiction: $k(f',g')=k(t)$ so there exist $\lambda,\mu \in k$ such that $\gcd(f'-\lambda,g'-\mu)=t-\nu$ for some $\nu \in k$. Therefore, $f',g'$ cannot generate the unit ideal. However, we changed $f',g'$ so the original $f,g$ also changed, and there is no guarantee that still $k(f,g)=k(t)$.